# Fill lookup via foreign key after insert

Tags: trigger, bulkification

Problem:
I have an external service bulk inserting a task and including a foreign key to my table `business`. 
The service will be creating ~100-500 tasks at a time.

I'm trying to build a bulkified trigger to perform a SOQL via the foreign key and then insert the correct id into the Task Related To/WhatId.

Example:

```
Task.Id: 00T54000007VTUOEA4
Task.WhatId: <null>
Task.BusinessUUID__c: 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000

Business__c.Id: a1m54000001uQZpAAM
Business__c.Business_UUID__c: 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

On insert of Task where:

```
iter = [select id,BusinessUUID__c from Task]

biz = [select id from Business where Business_UUID__c = :iter.BusinessUUID__c]
```

Update `Task.WhatId` with `biz.id`

Obviously, I'm trying to avoid calling the soql's above within a for loop so currently I'm considering assigning the entire `business` object to a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to adopt what we might call the collect-query-update pattern.

First, you iterate over records that contain some attribute by which you wish to query and accumulate the values of that attribute:

```
Set<String> businessUUIDs = new Set<String>();

for (Task t: Trigger.new) {
    if (t.Business_UUID__c != null) {
        businessUUIDs.add(t.Business_UUID__c);
    }
}
```

Then, you perform a query limited to just the parent objects you want. Typically, you'll want to turn this into a `Map` keyed on the attribute you're interested in:

```
Map<String, Business__c> businessMap = new Map<String, Business__c>();
for (Business__c b : [SELECT Id, Business_UUID__c FROM Business__c WHERE Business_UUID__c IN :businessUUIDs]) {
    businessMap.put(b.Business_UUID__c, b.Id);
}
```

(There's a one-liner for doing this by (ab)using query aliasing; I tend to prefer this explicit implementation for clarity).

And finally you iterate back over the initial records and update based on what you got in your `Map`:

```
for (Task t: Trigger.new) {
    if (businessMap.containsKey(t.Business_UUID__c)) {
        t.WhatId = businessMap.get(t.Business_UUID__c);
    }
}
```

(Assuming this is a `before insert` trigger).

There's some level of variation and elaboration possible here: what do you do if there are duplicate Business Ids on Businesses? What if a Task's Business Id is not found? and so forth. But the core pattern remains the same.